# Has Spring Framework 2.X reached EOL?

Tags: java, spring

We have a large code base of approximately 200,00 lines where Spring 2.X is used as the basic application development framework. We are thinking of undertaking a major (and painful) upgrade to Spring 4.X because of the simple reason that Spring 2.X does not seem to have any commercial support anymore.

I have also noticed that the last version of Spring Framework, 2.5.6, hasn't had any bug or security fixes for the past 5 years? Does this mean that Spring 2.X is an orphaned project?

http://sourceforge.net/projects/springframework/files/?source=directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring 2.X is definitely EOL-ed (and very long time ago).

> Once we have published a release candidate for a new version of a project, we will typically not release further tags or binary builds of earlier versions of the project to the open source community. Such releases will be available for three years to SpringSource Enterprise customers.

This means that it was EOL-ed when 3.0.0 was released, and of course, now, when 4.0.0. is already released.

Even the commercial support won't help you, as they support only 3 years back, and Spring 2.5.6 was released in Nov 2008.

Source:
http://spring.io/blog/2008/10/07/a-question-of-balance-tuning-the-maintenance-policy

Answer (score 0):

http://support.springsource.com/eol

Date: January 31, 2012 
Today, SpringSource, a division of VMware, announces that the End-Of-Life cycle for the following Spring projects is beginning.  Commercial support for these versions will end as of January 31, 2013.

- Spring Framework 2.5
- Spring Security 2.0
- Spring Web Flow 2.0
- Spring LDAP 1.2

Users of these versions are encouraged to upgrade prior to the End-Of-Life date.

Support can be reached through your portal at https://www.vmware.com/accounts.