# Spring/Java error: namespace element 'annotation-config' ... on JDK 1.5 and higher

Tags: java, spring, illegalstateexception

I have Spring/Java App that is compiled with **Compiler compliance level 1.5**.

I have a new Linux setup where I downloaded **Apache Tomcat 8.0.8**.

I downloaded **JDK 8u5**.

I set the path in bash as follows:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/jdk1.8.0_05/bin
export PATH
```

Java -version reports:

```
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

And set in setnenv.sh (for Tomcat):

```
JDK_HOME=/home/userid/jdk1.8.0_05
```

When I deploy my WAR file I get below error.
I think Tomcat doesn't seem to use the Java I installed.
I have followed the setup instructions.
PS: I also tried JRE instead of JDK and same issue.

```
22-May-2014 11:34:54.070 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
22-May-2014 11:34:54.512 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from file [/home/userid/apache-tomcat-8.0.8/webapps/myApplication-QA/WEB-INF/classes/config/spring/securityContext.xml]; nested exception is **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context namespace element 'annotation-config' and its parser class [org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigBeanDefinitionParser] are only available on JDK 1.5 and higher**
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5170)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1270)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:221)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1033)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context namespace element 'annotation-config' and its parser class [org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigBeanDefinitionParser] are only available on JDK 1.5 and higher
    at org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler$1.parse(ContextNamespaceHandler.java:65)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:69)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1253)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1243)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
    ... 49 more

22-May-2014 11:34:54.518 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

Comment: Try in `setenv.sh`: JAVA_HOME=/home/userid/jdk1.8.0_05

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I tried that and still no luck.
BTW: On Tomcat startup I get below.
bash startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/userid/apache-tomcat-8.0.8
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/userid/apache-tomcat-8.0.8
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/userid/apache-tomcat-8.0.8/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /home/userid/jdk1.8.0_05
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/userid/apache-tomcat-8.0.8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/userid/apache-tomcat-8.0.8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_PID:    /home/userid/apache-tomcat-8.0.8/tomcat.pid
Tomcat started.

Comment: You are using Spring 2.5?

Comment: Yes this is an old App.

Comment: @AndreiStefan replace jdk1.8... with a jdk 5, 6 or 7. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I encountered this problem because I got two apps running on the same machine - one requiring java 8, and one old one which depends on spring 2.5

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The class that's throwing the exception is using this code to check for Java version:

```
static {
        javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
        // version String should look like "1.4.2_10"
        if (javaVersion.indexOf("1.7.") != -1) {
            majorJavaVersion = JAVA_17;
        }
        else if (javaVersion.indexOf("1.6.") != -1) {
            majorJavaVersion = JAVA_16;
        }
        else if (javaVersion.indexOf("1.5.") != -1) {
            majorJavaVersion = JAVA_15;
        }
        else {
            // else leave 1.4 as default (it's either 1.4 or unknown)
            majorJavaVersion = JAVA_14;
        }
    }
```

So, when Spring 2.5 was first released, the code didn't assume it will be run in a Java version that's later than 1.7. For Java 8 and beyond, the code above will assume default 1.4 version. Because of this, the annotations part will complain.

I think you either need to upgrade your Spring version or use Java 7. [Spring 2.5 has been EOLed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882576/has-spring-framework-2-x-reached-eol) for quite some time now, anyway.

Comment: Stefan, That was it.
I downloaded JRE 1.7 and all is well.
Thank you for your help.
Robert

Comment: It appears like support for Java 8 was added in Spring >= 3.2.3. See the [code change](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.core/3.2.3/org/springframework/core/JdkVersion.java/?v=diff&id2=3.2.2) in `JdkVersion.class`.

Comment: Phew, this solution was simpler than I feared it would be. Thanks!

Comment: This has saved me a lot of headaches, thanks!

Answer (score 20):

I have the similar problem. Old Spring MVC/Spring Faces application  under spring 2.5.5 doesn't run on Java 8.

I spent few days trying to find solution because we need to run Java 8.

First idea was:  to upgrade complete Spring package up to 4.1.6. I used Maven. Problem of this method that after that it is  necessary to rework nearly the whole project.  It is  because for example in Spring 4 were removed JSF implementation and some special taglibs where completely removed, like `<sf:..>`. And were some more major and minor problems with configuration, adapters, handlers, mappings....

Second approach was to replace Spring JARs partially.One by one. Again no success. Impossible to replace any jar without touching dependencies.

I believe that after few weeks or monthes of struggling I can get success on both approaches. But have no so much time. And I gave up.
My solution is:

I found source file JdkVersion.java from org.springframework.core package. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgspringframeworkcoresources300releasejar.htm.
I created org.springframework.core package in my project with only one class JdkVersion. After that made simple change of the code to check Java 8 version. Smth like that:

```
public static final int JAVA_18 = 5;
```

...

```
        javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
    // version String should look like "1.4.2_10"
    if (javaVersion.contains("1.8.")) {
        majorJavaVersion = JAVA_18;         
        System.out.println("JAVA_VERSION: "+javaVersion);

    } else if (javaVersion.contains("1.7.")) {
        majorJavaVersion = JAVA_17;
    }
```

Even this code change is not really necessary, only just for fun.It is because this source came from Spring 3.0.0 package where Spring guys already changed the Java version check. Versions higher than 7 are not considered as old java.

Now application starts properly. It call JdkVersion class from my project instead of jar.

Works so far! Thanks for all from this thread who gave this idea.

Thanks

Comment: I have adapted this approach to my project which has multiple modules/subprojects in it. So what i did was i searched for the spring-xxx-version.jar on my  server directory( i was using tomcat ). I added a JdkVersion.class (that has check for java 8 as described above) in to the spring-xxx-version.jar and re-started the server. that fixed my problem.

Comment: That's good as well, you just patched original spring jars. Anyway this version of  spring is out of service.

Answer (score 16):

I need to support Spring 2.5.5 on Java 8, so I used the approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29647933/2074605) to provide a future-proof drop-in replacement for `JdkVersion.class` with as few side-effects as possible (nobody else posted a complete class, and I didn't want to hijack the other answer). There is no need to check for Java 8, simply default to Java 7, which is the highest version the class cared about:

Extract the jar file:

```
mkdir spring
cd spring
jar xvf ../spring.jar
```

Check the Spring version in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` (you should see something like `version=2.5.5`). Look up the [appropriate version](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-core/2.5.5/org/springframework/core/JdkVersion.java) of `JdkVersion.java` and use that as a starting point (the example below is for Spring 2.5.5 and you don't want to change any method signatures from the version you're working with).

Check the major and minor version of the `JdkVersion.class` file:

`javap -verbose org/springframework/core/JdkVersion.class`

We see that the class was original compiled as target **48.0** ([looking this up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27123/2074605), we find that is Java 1.4):

```
Classfile /tmp/spring/org/springframework/core/JdkVersion.class
  Last modified Jun 23, 2008; size 1286 bytes
  MD5 checksum 98e6ea08ce9186c50cc71d14465fc3dd
  Compiled from "JdkVersion.java"
public abstract class org.springframework.core.JdkVersion
  minor version: 0
  major version: 48
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER, ACC_ABSTRACT
Constant pool:
...
```

Create `org/springframework/core/JdkVersion.java` with the following content:

```
package org.springframework.core;

public abstract class JdkVersion
{
    public static final int JAVA_13 = 0;
    public static final int JAVA_14 = 1;
    public static final int JAVA_15 = 2;
    public static final int JAVA_16 = 3;
    public static final int JAVA_17 = 4;

    private static final String javaVersion;
    private static final int majorJavaVersion;

    static
    {
        javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");

        if (javaVersion.indexOf("1.7.") != -1)
        {
            majorJavaVersion = JAVA_17;
        } else if (javaVersion.indexOf("1.6.") != -1) {
            majorJavaVersion = JAVA_16;
        } else if (javaVersion.indexOf("1.5.") != -1) {
            majorJavaVersion = JAVA_15;
        } else if (javaVersion.indexOf("1.4.") != -1) { // new
            majorJavaVersion = JAVA_14;                 // new
        } else {
            majorJavaVersion = JAVA_17;                 // changed from JAVA_14
        }
    }

    public static String getJavaVersion()
    {
        return javaVersion;
    }

    public static int getMajorJavaVersion()
    {
        return majorJavaVersion;
    }

    public static boolean isAtLeastJava14()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isAtLeastJava15()
    {
        return getMajorJavaVersion() >= JAVA_15;
    }

    public static boolean isAtLeastJava16()
    {
        return getMajorJavaVersion() >= JAVA_16;
    }
}
```

Then compile the new class as Java 1.4:

`javac -source 1.4 org/springframework/core/JdkVersion.java`

You can check the major.minor version again as above if needed.

Create the modified jar file (without overwriting the original manifest):

`jar Mcf ../spring-modified.jar *`

Copy the modified jar file where needed (as `spring.jar` or as appropriate).

Comment: @SunilShevante No problem, I'm glad this helped you out!

Answer (score 10):

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring</artifactId>
<version>2.5.6</version>
```

TO =>

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

OR

1. Right click on project property.
2. Go to/ Click on "Java Build Path".
3. Select Libraries tab and double click on "JRE System Libry"
4. On that pop up select the JDK 1.7 (If you dont have JDK 1.7 ,first install   it, then select it from "Execution environment")

[image: Property]

Answer (score 5):

i had the same problem, but i have a solution:

in your project file pom.xml replace:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

for:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and say good bye to your problems!!

This two dependecies are the replacement for the firts dependency in the most part.

Answer (score 3):

I happen to be another unfortunate user of a very old project (developed in 2008!) which is still using Spring 2.5. And it is not a Maven project either, so upgrading to later versions of Spring was taking a long time with dependencies failing and giving build errors. I downgraded tomcat JRE to 1.7 and it worked fine.

Just documenting how to do that in eclipse in case someone needs help:

1. If you do not already have Java 7, download JDK 7 and install it
   somewhere like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71`
2. Then go to eclipse and double click on `Servers > Tomcat vX.Y server`
3. Click on `Runtime Environment`, then `Installed JREs`
4. Then `Add` > `Standard VM` and click `Next`. You see a window like
   this:

   [image: Adding a new JRE]
5. Click on `Directory...` and browse to the folder where you installed
   the JDK (i.e. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71`. JDK is fine, no
   need for JRE). Click `Finish`.
6. Then make sure to select the JRE for Java 7 and you are all set.

Answer (score 3):

Migrate your spring version from 2.5 to >=3.2.3.

For Spring migration you need to do following changes -

1) In your pom.xml remove dependency for spring 2.5.6 and add dependency for spring new version.

2) Update 'xsi:schemaLocation' in beans tag of applicationcontet.xml file of your project.

e.g update http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd to 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd for spring 3.2.3 version.

3) Clean,build and re-deploy your project.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. But, after trying very hard, I found out that this is because of using Java 1.8. I changed it to 1.6 and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I created a fully automatic version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32487035/2074605).
Please read that post first for the subtleties he addresses.

- create an ant build file with the contents below the bullets
- copy `spring.jar` next to the `build.xml` file
- run the patch target
- you are done, the file is patched

`build.xml` file contents:

```
<project name="spring-patch" default="patch">
    <target name="patch">
        <mkdir dir="src/org/springframework/core"/>
        <get dest="src/org/springframework/core/JdkVersion.java"
                src="http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring/2.5.5/org/springframework/core/JdkVersion.java/?v=source&amp;disposition=attachment" />
        <replace dir="src" value="majorJavaVersion = JAVA_17">
          <replacetoken>majorJavaVersion = JAVA_14</replacetoken>
        </replace>
        <javac srcdir="src" />
        <zip destfile="spring.jar" update="true">
            <fileset dir="src" includes="**/*.class" />
        </zip>
        <delete dir="src" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though this answer has been perfectly answered, in some cases it's not desired or possible to upgrade the Java version or the Spring version.

In our case, we have to use JDK 8 to be able to communicate with Sonar (from Jenkins) and we don't want to change the spring-version, because we don't have the test capacity to test this upgrade.

Our solution was to simply override the Java version while building, using

```
-Djava.version=1.6.45
```

Answer (score 2):

I've added support java1.8 and java1.9 to spring 2.5.
Please replace file in your tomacat lib.
JdkVersion.class - changed

[download spring.jar](http://jteam.ru/jar/spring.jar)