# Why am I getting a JDK 1.5 related error message in Java 8?

Tags: java, spring

Exception message

> Context namespace element 'component-scan' and its parser class
>   [org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser]
>   are only available on JDK 1.5 and higher

Java -version

```
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You may have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813369/spring-java-error-namespace-element-annotation-config-on-jdk-1-5-and-high. You may need to upgrade your Spring to newer version.

Comment: please tell us what you see when you writing `java -version` at windows cmd

Comment: How are compiling ? Are you using Maven ? Intellij ?

Comment: If you are using Maven check your Java version in `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your issue is not with the java version, but with your spring version. take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813369/spring-java-error-namespace-element-annotation-config-on-jdk-1-5-and-high). Upgrade to newer spring version