# WAS 8.5 Java 8 and Spring 2.5.6

Tags: java, spring, java-8, websphere, websphere-8

Am updating my application which is running in WAS7 and JDK6 to WAS8.5 and JDK8.
In my application there were 3 projects. two of them are in spring 3+ which i migrated succesfully. But the third one is in Spring 2.5.6.

While migratig i got below exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource is only available on Java 1.5 and higher
at org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceUtils.getAnnotationTransactionAttributeSourceClass(TxNamespaceUtils.java:43)
at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser$AopAutoProxyConfigurer.configureAutoProxyCreator(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:115)
at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:80)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:69)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1297)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
... 102 more
```

First i thought Spring 2.5.6 and Java 8 compatibility issue, so i tried with WAS8.5 and java7 and later with Java6.

But still same issue.

Please help me.

Thank You.

Comment: The following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813369/spring-java-error-namespace-element-annotation-config-on-jdk-1-5-and-high does make it seem that the issue is with Spring 2.5 with Java 8.  When you switched Java versions are you sure you were actually running with Java 6/7 instead of Java 8?

Comment: how to make sure it..?

Comment: If you look in SystemOut (under profiles/<your_profile_name>/logs/<your_server_name>/SystemOut.log) it is listed in the header under `Java version = <java_version_here>`.  See https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/which_java_version_is_my_websphere_application_server_8_5_using?lang=en for further details.