# AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource is only available on Java 1.5 and higher appears even when using 1.7. Why?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am dealing with this problem here. I am using IntelliJ Community Edition and Tomcat 7.

I have set the project SDK to 1.7 and also the module SDK to 1.7.

Spring version is 4.1.6.RELEASE (and it must not be changed).

When I deploy the war file to tomcat I am getting:

```
    ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-15] ContextLoader:215 - Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/config/spring/appContext-common.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource is only available on Java 1.5 and higher
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:420)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5157)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5680)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1320)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:683)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:209)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:603)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1136)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource is only available on Java 1.5 and higher
        at org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceUtils.getAnnotationTransactionAttributeSourceClass(TxNamespaceUtils.java:43)
        at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser$AopAutoProxyConfigurer.configureAutoProxyCreator(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:115)
        at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:80)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:69)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1297)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
        ... 47 more
Jul 31, 2018 11:46:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Jul 31, 2018 11:46:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
```

I have already read and followed the solutions suggested in this article

[Spring/Java error: namespace element 'annotation-config' ... on JDK 1.5 and higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813369/spring-java-error-namespace-element-annotation-config-on-jdk-1-5-and-high?noredirect=1#comment90183392_51609257)

but the problem persists.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you are using a mix of jars from different versions. Looking at the 4.1 source code I cannot find the `TxNamespaceUtils.getAnnotationTransactionAttributeSourceClass`. Make sure you aren't mixing jars of different versions of the framework.

Comment: The class `TxNamespaceUtils` doesn't exist anymore (somewhere as of Spring 3.0) so something is pulling in Spring 2.x dependencies leading to these kind of weird issues.