# Cannot resolve reference to bean MapExecutionContextDao

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am new to Spring, and I've encountered this error while trying to upgrade our project from Java 6 to Java 8.

```
    00:51:42,543 ERROR main CommandLineJobRunner:355 - Job Terminated in error: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [app-c
ontext/bprpp-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context namespace element 'annotation-config' and its parser class [o
rg.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigBeanDefinitionParser] are only available on JDK 1.5 and higher
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [app-context/bprpp
-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context namespace element 'annotation-config' and its parser class [org.springfra
mework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigBeanDefinitionParser] are only available on JDK 1.5 and higher
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:420)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:113)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:80)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:12
3)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:282)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:574)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context namespace element 'annotation-config' and its parser class [org.springframework.context.annotatio
n.AnnotationConfigBeanDefinitionParser] are only available on JDK 1.5 and higher
        at org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler$1.parse(ContextNamespaceHandler.java:65)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:69)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1297)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:13
5)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java
:92)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
        ... 15 more
2018-09-20 00:51:42 - ***** step050 - java rc=1
```

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813369/spring-java-error-namespace-element-annotation-config-on-jdk-1-5-and-high) that to resolve this, either use Java 7 or upgrade Spring version. Java 7 wont do since my goal is to upgrade to Java 8 so I tried upgrading the Spring version from 2.1.9 to 4.0.0 and I got the following errors:

```
14:45:27,006 ERROR main CommandLineJobRunner:370 - Job Terminated in error: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [app-context/bprpp-memory-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'executionContextDao' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'executionContextDao' defined in class path resource [app-context/bprpp-memory-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapExecutionContextDao]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/DecoratingProxy
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [app-context/bprpp-memory-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'executionContextDao' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'executionContextDao' defined in class path resource [app-context/bprpp-memory-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapExecutionContextDao]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/DecoratingProxy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:616)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:292)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:596)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'executionContextDao' defined in class path resource [app-context/bprpp-memory-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapExecutionContextDao]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/DecoratingProxy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapExecutionContextDao]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/DecoratingProxy
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/DecoratingProxy
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils.completeProxiedInterfaces(AopProxyUtils.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:113)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:97)
    at org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.TransactionAwareProxyFactory.createInstance(TransactionAwareProxyFactory.java:154)
    at org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.TransactionAwareProxyFactory.createAppendOnlyTransactionalMap(TransactionAwareProxyFactory.java:170)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapExecutionContextDao.<init>(MapExecutionContextDao.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 40 more
```

Here are the related files:

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xcel.brp</groupId>
    <artifactId>BRP-BATCH</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>BRP-BATCH</name>
    <!-- <url>http://maven.apache.org</url> -->

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <!-- <junit.version>4.4</junit.version> -->
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <snowdrop.version>2.0.0.Final</snowdrop.version>
        <commons-logging.version>1.1.1</commons-logging.version>
        <cxf.version>2.4.6</cxf.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.5.8</slf4j.version>
        <spp.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</spp.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
        <!-- <spring-batch.version>2.1.9.RELEASE</spring-batch.version> -->
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version> -->
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>${spring-batch.version}</version> -->
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-logging.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm-tiger</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                    <include>**/*.gwt.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

bprpp-memory-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd"> 

    <bean id="jobRepository" 
          class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="jobInstanceDao"      />
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="jobExecutionDao"     />
        <constructor-arg index="2" ref="stepExecutionDao"    />
        <constructor-arg index="3" ref="executionContextDao" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jobInstanceDao" 
          class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobInstanceDao" />

    <bean id="jobExecutionDao" 
          class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobExecutionDao" />

    <bean id="stepExecutionDao" 
          class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapStepExecutionDao" />

    <bean id="executionContextDao" 
          class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapExecutionContextDao" />

    <bean id="jobExplorer" 
          class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.SimpleJobExplorer">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="jobInstanceDao"      />
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="jobExecutionDao"     />
        <constructor-arg index="2" ref="stepExecutionDao"    />
        <constructor-arg index="3" ref="executionContextDao" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobLauncher" 
          class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher" >     
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />        
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" 
          class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" /> 

</beans>
```

Comment: You upgraded spring-batch-core which requires a higher version of spring-core. Try to change spring-version in your pom.xml to 4.3.10.RELEASE or higher. You can check the dependencies of spring-batch-core here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-core/4.0.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the typical kind of problems that are solved with a maven BOM. For spring projects, I would recommend using the [Spring Boot BOM](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent) instead of importing dependencies and specifying versions manually. This BOM will bring spring dependencies that are known to work well together. You can use this BOM even if you don't use Spring Boot.

In your case, If you use Spring Boot version 2.0.5.RELEASE, it will bring spring Batch 4.0.1.RELEASE along with spring Framework 5.0.9.RELEASE.

Hope this helps.